# add NSDictionary as a value for a NSDictionary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to add a different Dictionary as a value for an other key dictionary, but in the and of my loop I find the same values added to all my dictionary keys.
Here's my code:

```
for (MyObject *message in messages) {
        int value = [key intValue] +1;

[mess setObject:message.body forKey:@"msg"];
        [mess setObject:message.bareJidStr forKey:@"sender"];
        [mess setObject:[element attributeStringValueForName:@"to"] forKey:@"reciever"];
        [mess setObject:message.timestamp forKey:@"date"];
        [[self messagesHistory] setObject:mess forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value]];
}
```

There's something which is not working properly, but I can;t figure out where !
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `I want to add a different Dictionary as a value for an other key dictionary` thats not clear can you re-word that please

Comment: Of course meda, for each key of my Dictionary A I want to add a Dictionary B as it's Value, hope that's clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are adding a same dictionary

you must have this line before the loop

```
NSMutableDictionary *mess = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

so you only created **one** dictionary and use it as the value for **all** keys

you need to move this line inside the loop

```
for (MyObject *message in messages) {
        // create a new dictionary for each value
        NSMutableDictionary *mess = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        int value = [key intValue] +1;

        [mess setObject:message.body forKey:@"msg"];
        [mess setObject:message.bareJidStr forKey:@"sender"];
        [mess setObject:[element attributeStringValueForName:@"to"] forKey:@"reciever"];
        [mess setObject:message.timestamp forKey:@"date"];
        [[self messagesHistory] setObject:mess forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value]];
}
```

Comment: Yep, dumb error, I lost 1 hour on it :s sorry, and thank you Bryan

Answer (score 1):

Make an object of "mess" inside the loop, otherwise the same "mess" object is used for all values.

```
for (MyObject *message in messages) 
{
    int value = [key intValue] +1;

    mess = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [mess setObject:message.body forKey:@"msg"];
        [mess setObject:message.bareJidStr forKey:@"sender"];
        [mess setObject:[element attributeStringValueForName:@"to"] forKey:@"reciever"];
        [mess setObject:message.timestamp forKey:@"date"];
        [[self messagesHistory] setObject:mess forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value]];
}
```